# How to query against ObjectId when not in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, objectid

I'm working on paging functionality using a range query.  I'm using this test query in the mongo shell:

```
> var params =  {$query: {_id: {$lt: ObjectId("52b06166eff887999c6efbd9")}}, $orderby: {_id: -1}, $maxScan: 3}
> params
{
  "$query" : {
    "_id" : {
      "$lt" : ObjectId("52b06166eff887999c6efbd9")
    }
  },
  "$orderby" : {
    "_id" : -1
  },
  "$maxScan" : 3
}
> db.events.find(params)
```

I'd like to be able to pass the serialized params object to a web service (as a URL query string).  However, the `ObjectId` class is only available inside the shell.  Is there a way to specify an `ObjectId` as part of a query when not in the shell?  I've tried the following as the value of `$lt` without success:

```
'ObjectId("52b06166eff887999c6efbd9")'
'new ObjectId("52b06166eff887999c6efbd9")'
{"$oid" : "52b06166eff887999c6efbd9"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this abstraction is handled by whatever MongoDB driver you use.  If you are using an actual driver, you can do queries on `_id` without using `ObjectId()`

Mongoose / Node.js Example:

```
People.find({ _id : "Valid ObjectID String" }, function(e, person) {
  console.log(e, person);
});
```

If you do still need the `ObjectId` helper, generally you are able to reference it in whatever native driver you need.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though as I also mentioned below, I'm doing this in client-side JavaScript, so I'm not sure if there's an applicable driver...

Comment: @ytran In that case, it all comes down to how the request gets ran into the `mongo` shell. From the sounds of it, what you are probably doing is writing a file and piping it into the `mongo` shell. If that's the case, you could parse the _id field and replace the _id string with `ObjectId(` + string + `)`

Comment: @ytran You should be careful however, it's quite easy to bring down a MongoDB instance.  For example, this query could be passed into your webhook: `{ "$where" : "while(1=1){};" }`

Comment: That's not exactly what we're doing, but as far as the behavior goes you nailed it on the head. I was playing around with `new Date(...)` independently and saw the same thing happening.  So this would be a reasonable workaround. However, from what you're saying in the second comment, we should be re-thinking this approach.  Thanks!

Comment: @ytran Yep, unless you personally know the users, it's best to not approach accessing MongoDB that way.  You can do even more nefarious stuff inside the `mongo` shell, depending on the flexibility you are giving to the users.  You could do something like `use admin`, `db.shutdownServer()`, or `show dbs`, `for db in dbs, use db, db.dropDatabase()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your last examples is passing your objectId as a string (first two examples) or as a dictionary third example. So surely it does not work.

You can pass just a string '`52b06166eff887999c6efbd9`' as a parameter and then when you receive it you can construct normal `ObjectId` on the server. For example in php you can construct it in the following way [new MongoId('your string');](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Unfortunately in this case I'm using an existing web service, so there is no server side to speak of.